# Pros and cons of different JavaScript closures

Tags: javascript, closures

I was brushing up on some [good JavaScript practise, courtesy of Douglas Crockford](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=wUdN7-gy6f0), when something struck me about one of his examples regarding closure. He gives two example variants of a simple program (amongst many others), as shown below:

**Example 1:**

```
var digit_names = function(n) {
    var names = ['zero', 'one', 'two', 'three',
        'four', 'five', 'six', 'seven', 'eight', 'nine'];

    return names[n];
};

digit_names(3); // three
```

**Example 2:**

```
var digit_names = ( function(n) {
    var names = ['zero', 'one', 'two', 'three',
        'four', 'five', 'six', 'seven', 'eight', 'nine'];

    return function() {
        return names[n];
    };
}());

digit_names(3); // three
```

His main comment about the first example is that it has to create an array in memory every time the function runs. Whereas in the second example - although it's not explicitly mentioned - I'm lead to believe that the array would become a property of the `digit_names` function object, that's stored in memory one time only.

Despite being a trivial example, I can clearly see the benefits of the second pattern as the array doesn't need to be allocated to memory repeatedly.

What I'm less clear on is whether that's the only gain, or are there any other advantages that the second example can provide?

Also, are there any (probably edge) cases where it could possibly make more sense to use the first paradigm? Are there any potential limitations due to the use of an IIFE wrapper?

Comment: I think the main purpose of the example is to explain closures, rather than recommending this as a useful pattern. Personally I would go for code that is *readable* and goes for optimisation only when required. You could read [Javascript design patterns](https://addyosmani.com/resources/essentialjsdesignpatterns/book/) to explore different patterns and advantages.

Comment: Also note that array in example1 is available for Garbage collection while the array in example2 is retained in memory until all references are dead. Sometimes causing memory leaks when things get complex.

Comment: Interesting point about the garbage collection. It's not a subject I've ever looked into, but I think I get the general idea.